# Custom swatch guide color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I created a custom swatch color, I want to set this color as my Guide color.
I tried Edit > Preferences > Guides & Grid > custom but you can't select a swatch nor you can pick a color (with colorpick)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use swatches.. but you *can* use the operating system color picker.. just click the little color box ....

[image]